# Write a Query to show Id, Name and No. of department?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to write a Query to show Id, Name and No. of department in given Table which are referring more than one department.

```
ID      Name     Department
--      ----     ----------
1       Sam      HR
1       Sam      FINANCE
2       Ron      PAYROLL
3       Kia      HR
3       Kia      IT
```

Result :

```
ID      Name     Department
--      ----     ----------
1       Sam               2
3       Kia               2
```

I tried using `group by id` and using `count(*)`, but query is giving error.

How can I do this?

Comment: Why do you not show us your query? Why do you not tell us what error you get? Help us help you!

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing your query, a blind guess is that you wrongly wrote the `GROUP BY` clause (if you used it) and forgot to include the `HAVING` clause.

Anyway, something like this might be what you're looking for:

```
SQL> with test (id, name, department) as
  2    (select 1, 'sam', 'hr'      from dual union
  3     select 1, 'sam', 'finance' from dual union
  4     select 2, 'ron', 'payroll' from dual union
  5     select 3, 'kia', 'hr'      from dual union
  6     select 3, 'kia', 'it'      from dual
  7    )
  8  select id, name, count(*)
  9  from test
 10  group by id, name
 11  having count(*) > 1
 12  order by id;

        ID NAM   COUNT(*)
---------- --- ----------
         1 sam          2
         3 kia          2

SQL>
```

Comment: I only did grouping by id. Not by both.

Comment: Oh well, that happens :)

Comment: Any explaination why do we need both?

Comment: Such are the rules.

Answer (score 1):

You can use *window* function with `subquery` :

```
select distinct id, name, Noofdepartment
from (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by id,name) Noofdepartment
      from table t
     ) t
where Noofdepartment > 1;
```

However, you can also use `group by` clause:

```
select id, name, count(*) as Noofdepartment
from table t
group by id, name
having count(*) > 1;
```

Comment: The first query won't work; `*` misses a table name (or its alias).

Answer (score 1):

You were right about using `count()`. You need to group by other columns though and only count unique departments then filter on the number in having clause.

```
select id, name, count(distinct department) as no_of_department
from table
group by id, name
having count(distinct department) > 1
```

This can also be done using analytic functions like below:

```
select *
from (
  select id, name, count(distinct department) over (partition by id, name) as no_of_department
  from table
) t
where no_of_department > 1
```

Comment: What are analytic functions

Comment: Added another solution

Comment: How count(*) is different from count(distinct department) as others have answered?

Comment: I've already explained that in my answer. It only counts unique departments. If you would have duplicate row, it would only properly count it once.